# Umbraco: Deny public access for media files of content

Tags: iis, web-config, umbraco, media, public

I'm working with Umbraco 4.11.8.

For my website I have a document type, that contains a field to upload PDF files. The created content items of this document type aren't public so a specific membergroup can see them, only. That works fine.

But... When I type the specific path of the PDF file in the browser, it will show me, but it shouldn't. It just has to be visible for logged in members.

Is there a way to do this with umbraco or do I have to do this with the webserver (IIS 7) and the web.config? I'm able to deny the access of all media files in the media folder, but there are images and files for public, too. So that isn't the solution.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at this package 'media protect'; 
http://our.umbraco.org/projects/website-utilities/media-protect

We've used it on several projects with great success. It works well and is a solid solution.

Comment: Thanks.
It's exactly what I'm looking for, but the negative point is that it isn't free.
So you probably know a way to do this without any costs.